# Write data to different directory for shiny-app

Tags: r, linux, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny-app on linux running shiny-server. Following my setup the apps are located in `/srv/shiny-server/app-dir/`.

I want to write a file to that directory for my shiny-app to read, using a `.R` file that I put together. In that file I write the data like this: `write.csv(df, "file.csv")`. If I run this file from my shiny-app directory using 
`Rscript /srv/shiny-server/app-dir/write_script.R`, it writes the data to `/home/ec2-user`.

If I change the `write` command to `write.csv(df, '/srv/shiny-server/app-dir/data.csv')` and run the same way it does not work (permission denied).

Nor can I read files in `/home/ec2-user/` from within my shiny-app.

So my question is: how can I write files from an R script (not the server.R file in a shiny app) that can be accessed by my shiny-app, given my folder structure outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

Shiny Apps are executed by user `shiny`, which has no access to the `home`-directory of the user `ec2-user`. You can change the reading permissions of the file just after copying it into `/srv/shiny-server/app-dir`:

- With a linux command: `chmod a+r /srv/shiny-server/app-dir/file.csv`
- with an R command: `system2("chmod", list("a+r", "/srv/shiny-server/app-dir/file.csv")`

Comment: I think my issue is not with permissions on the `.csv` file but with getting the file into the `/srv/shiny-server` directory in the first place. I did not know about the `system2` function, would this work in my script that writes the `.csv` to move the file to `/srv/shiny-server`? Something like: `system2("cp", list("/home/ec2-user/file.csv", "/srv/shiny-server/app-dir))`. Can I add `sudo` to `system2` and have it work?